# Check if a module exists, if so replace console with it, otherwise not. Not working, console gets undefined

Tags: node.js, console.log, node-modules, clim

I'm using [clim](https://github.com/epeli/node-clim) and I replace the `console` object with it. But I only want to replace it if the module exists.

```
try {
    var console = require('clim')();
} catch(err) {}
console.log('checking..');
```

If the module doesn't exists it makes the `console` undefined.

Strangely, saving the console object and replacing doesn't work either

```
var console_backup = console;
try {
    var console = require('clim')();
} catch(err) {
    if (err) var console = console_backup;
}
console.log('checking..');
```

Still throws error (`console` goes undefined) when `clim` doesn't exist.

http://runnable.com/U8vlFEpIYtkiV2N9/24850946-console-for-node-js

How to make work replacing the `console` with `clim` ***only*** when it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt is close, but you need to explicitly identity that you want to reference the global `console` when setting `console_backup` or it will reference the hoisted, local `console` variable, even though you haven't declared it yet:

```
var console_backup = global.console;
try {
    var console = require('clim')();
} catch(err) {
    if (err) var console = console_backup;
}
console.log('checking..');
```

or simplify it to:

```
try {
    var console = require('clim')();
} catch(err) {
    if (err) console = global.console;
}
console.log('checking..');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't overwrite the global `console` like that. The `var console` is just creating a local variable that shadows the global `console`, not even `global.console = ...` will work.

You could overwrite `console.log`, etc. individually or overwrite `process.stdout.write` (what `console.log` uses internally) which would allow you to hook into stdout writing at a lower level. This would also catch anyone else that may use `process.stdout.write` directly.

Comment: I don't want to overwrite. Just want to create a local `console` variable if `clim` exists, just like it does when it *does* exist. Unfortunately it's still getting overwritten anyways with `undefined` object.